# Why am I having two grub menus?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, efi

I just installed ubuntu on my external hard drive and then try to turn on my computer I encounter a blank grub 2.40 menu([this blank grub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlu0y.jpg)) and after that when I type exit command, it takes me to another grub menu which is like this ([GRUB2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy9l6.jpg)). It's happening every single time I turn on my pc even if I remove my E-HDD I m still getting that blank grub menu and I have to type exit command every time.

My question is why is this happening? and what can I do to remove that blank grub menu?

Comment: This probably has to do with your EFI entry.  Can you list which entries you have?

Comment: Do you have perhaps both EFI and GRUB?

Comment: @harrymc yes grub files in ubuntu and EFI files in windows(sorry if I said something wrong i m a nerd in linux)

Comment: @Ramhound sorry I don't know how to do that

Comment: You will have to research the best way to list EFI entries within Linux.  You will also need to eventually modify those entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you have used the Ubuntu installer for installing
Ubuntu to a second drive on a computer in which Windows was already
installed.

The Ubuntu installer has installed an entry into the windows EFI
partition, which basically only chains to its own EFI partition
on the second disk.

You may test this theory by checking if you have two EFI partitions.
One may be found on the Windows disk and the other on the Linux disk
(although they can still both be on the same disk).

I would guess that in such a case, that you should restore the
Windows bootloader, as in the post
[Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader),
then reinstall Linux. Be sure to use an EFI boot media for Ubuntu.

Comment: OKAY I resolved my problem through this post :(https://www.58bits.com/blog/2020/02/28/how-create-truly-portable-ubuntu-installation-external-usb-hdd-or-ssd). I think when I was installing Ubuntu on my external drive I wasn't installing grub on my Linux to make it truly bootable. After following this tutorial now I just have to plug in my HDD and select boot priority.The efi files of ubuntu on windows was causing problem as it was searching for Linux even when it was disconnected.